# Python: Opening a program in a new terminal [Linux]

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi

I am writing a bootstrap program that runs several individual programs simultaneously. Thus, I require each sub-program to have its own terminal window, in a manner that gives me the ability to start/stop each sub-program individually within the bootstrap.

I was able to do this on Windows using Popen and CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE (each sub-program has it's own .py file), however I am having trouble achieving this with Linux. I am using a Raspberry Pi and Python 2.7.9.

I have tried:

`Subprogram = Popen([executable, 'Foo.py'], shell=True)`

However this does not seem to create a new window.. and

`os.system("python ./Foo.py")`

Does not seem to create a new window nor allow me to terminate the process.

Other research has thus far proved unfruitful..

How can I do this? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: You could always use [screen](https://www.rackaid.com/blog/linux-screen-tutorial-and-how-to/) to launch them all in the same terminal window

Answer (score 4):

I finally figured it out, but wanted to post the solution so others can find it in the future.

`Subprogram = Popen(['lxterminal', '-e', 'python ./Foo.py'], stdout=PIPE)`

The `lxterminal` is the Raspberry Pi's terminal name, `-e` is required, `python ./Foo.py` launches the python file, and `stdout=PIPE` displays the output on the new terminal window.

Running the above launches Foo.py in a new terminal window, and allows the user to terminate the Foo.py process if desired.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
os.system("gnome-terminal --disable-factory")
```

It forces it to open a new process.

Comment: gnome-terminal is not on raspberry pi, and (please correct me if I am wrong) I do not believe I can kill an os.system process remotely.